# How to hide offline custom module of magento when total amount is more than 100 $

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7

My module file is

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Example extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'example';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return ['example' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return bool|Result
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('example');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('example');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        /*you can fetch shipping price from different sources over some APIs, we used price from config.xml - xml node price*/
        $amount = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to hide the shipping method when the total amount is greater than $100?

Comment: I want to hide this shipping module when price is greater than 100 .

Comment: Will you price be available in  $amount variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your price is available in $amount variable

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier('example');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod('example');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    /*you can fetch shipping price from different sources over some APIs, we used price from config.xml - xml node price*/
    $amount = $this->getConfigData('price');

    // Hide the shipping method when price is greated than $100
    if($amount > 100){
        return false;
    }

    $method->setPrice($amount);
    $method->setCost($amount);

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
}
```